# Cannot access inner Array of objects using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

so i have this array which has info about parent and child pages. im trying to print it out using ng-repeat but i only seem to get the first level of data.i cannot seem to access the inner child data.Any help is gratefully accepted

Here what ive tried so far

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages" >{{page.post_title}}
            <div ng-repeat="child in page.children">{{child.post_title}}</div>
        </div>

$scope.pages=[
{
    "id": "1",
    "post_title": "Batman Ipsum",
    "publish_date": "Monday, October 12th 2015, 9:35:16 pm",
    "is_draft": "0",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "post_title": "TV Ipsum",
            "publish_date": "Monday, October 12th 2015, 11:44:24 pm",
            "is_draft": "0",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "post_title": "Yet another Batman Ipsum",
                    "publish_date": "Thursday, October 22nd 2015, 11:00:00 pm",
                    "is_draft": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "post_title": "Title fit for a (precariously enthroned) king",
    "publish_date": "Monday, October 12th 2015, 10:07:01 pm",
    "is_draft": "0"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "post_title": "Cupcake Ipsum",
    "publish_date": "Monday, October 12th 2015, 10:13:23 pm",
    "is_draft": "0"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "post_title": "The most presidential lorem ipsum in history.",
    "publish_date": "Monday, October 12th 2015, 10:27:15 pm",
    "is_draft": "0"
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "post_title": "Quote Ipsum",
    "publish_date": "Null",
    "is_draft": "1"
}
]
```

but the result i get is

```
Batman Ipsum
TV Ipsum
Title fit for a (precariously enthroned) king
Cupcake Ipsum
The most presidential lorem ipsum in history.
Quote Ipsum
```

none of the children are printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need one more `<div ng-repeat="item in child.children"></div>` to get access the child of child parent!

> or if your last child is always one you can access them by `child[0].id`